# fitbit Oauth ssl connection error

Tags: oauth, fitbit

I've moved my server with another provider, my app was working without issue until I made the migration, now everytime I try to connect with fitbit I get this error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'making the request failed (SSL connect error)' in /var/www/html/includes/fitbitphp.php:188 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/includes/fitbitphp.php(188): OAuth->getRequestToken('https://api.fit...', 'https://gtefina...') #1 /var/www/html/fitbit.php(26): FitBitPHP->initSession('https://gtefina...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/includes/fitbitphp.php on line 188
```

I'm using this class as a wrapper https://github.com/heyitspavel/fitbitphp

I've been looking around in several configs of the server but I ran out of options, any idea?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to update your root CA (Certification Authority) on your new web server.